# ссылки кириллица modx

Tags: php, modx

```
<li><a href="[[!getAliasRegion?]][[~1]]?id=main-start">Тут какой-то текст</a></li>
```

сейчас ссылка выглядит так site.ru/товары/?id=main-start, как сделать в modx что бы ссылка стала site.ru/товары/#тут_какой-то_текст,

Comment: `<li><a href="[[!getAliasRegion?]][[~1]]#тут_какой-то_текст">Тут какой-то текст</a></li>`

Comment: тогда же путь к шаблону теряется, если бы всё так было просто )

Comment: Вроде в первом комментарии все правильно, если так сделаете, какую ссылку получаете? и причем тут путь к шаблону, как вы задали вопрос, там просто к ссылке должен дополняться якорем, в первом комментарии так и есть

Comment: так когда пользователь тыкает по "Тут какой-то текст" то он скролится на ту самою статью, которая находится на странице, если взять так как выше прислал человек, то скролится не будет (

Comment: а в самой статье вы такой же якорь вставляете? например `<div id="Тут какой-то текст">статья</div>` или тогда вообще непонятно что вы планируете сделать. Еще раз, если сделать как в первом комментарии, какую ссылку вы получаете? и чем она отличается от того, что вы хотите. Якорь он и добавляется для скролла в нужное место

Comment: есть выпадающее меню, <section class="main-start order-[[+sort]]" id="main-start"> вот id к которому общается, нужно изменить ссылки которые в меню с https://test.site.ru/тут-есть-текст/#на-тот-же-id , это делается для сео

Comment: https://сайт.рф/[название-страницы]?id=[подзаголовок-на-английском]-это как сейчас, а нужно https://сайт.рф/[название-страницы]#[подзаголовок-на-русском]
при этом что бы скрол сохранился

Comment: тогда вам внутри каждой статьи надо добавлять якорь на русском. т.е. внутри к примеру <section class="about-achieve section order-3" id="about-achieve"> - этой секции вставить <div id="наши достижения"></div> - просто пустой блок чтобы на него можно было ссылаться по идентификатору, тогда будет правильно открываться ссылка сайт.рф/[название-страницы]#наши достижения правда насчет пробелов в якоре не уверен

Comment: работает только если добавить id а не #

Comment: и без id работает, я на вашем и проверял, только с английским https://test.ru/как-мы-помогаем#about-achieve - переходит на нужный блок, просто такое id уже есть, на русском его надо добавить и так же по идее должен переходить

Comment: <li class="[[!If? &subject=`[[*id]]` &operator=`eq` &operand=`1` &then=`isActive` ]]"> не переходит потому что у меня наверно тут условие не правильное